# Typoscript Condition: backend_layout (with slide)

Tags: typo3

I use this condition

`[globalVar = GP:colPos==0]&&[page|backend_layout = pagets__MainTemplate]`

My problem is that my „subpage“ has no backend_layout selected because the parent pages "Backend Layout (subpages of this page)“ is set. So the condition does not work on subpages.

Can create a condition like that?

```
lib.backendLayout = TEXT
lib.backendLayout {
    data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    override.data = TSFE:page|backend_layout
}
```

I want do white/blacklist CTypes in BE Columns in this way:

```
[globalVar = GP:colPos==0]&&[page|backend_layout = pagets__MainTemplate]
    TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.keepItems := addToList(header)
[end]
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to explain what you want to achieve. You've already chosen a solution (a condition) for a problem only you know.

Comment: Thanks for the info - i updated the my Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know, as you can only access the current page record with the "page" condition.

Instead you could

a) Write your own condition (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#custom-conditions or starting with version 9 https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference.html#extending-the-expression-language-with-own-functions-like-old-userfunc)

b) Use a userFunc (like "a" only older and less fancy ;)) - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#userfunc

new c) follow Jigals suggestion (or use a similar extension - there are a few - but they mostly do a lot more than what you need)

--- EDIT after question update ---

As you want it working in TSConfig c) is actually not an option.

c) depending on what you actually want to achieve with your condition use if and data (like in your description) directly at the TS objects that should have different behavior if your condition is true.

For reference:

Differences between TSConfig Conditions and TS Conditions:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/8.7/Conditions/Index.html#differences-to-conditions-in-typoscript-templates

Comment: Yes, you are actually looking for the feature which the original author of that ticket thought to have found. But as you can see from the comments no such feature exists in conditions, only as part of stdWrap in TS Objects.

Comment: Links in this answer are dead.

Comment: Updated dead links.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Susi's solutions you could use Gridelements. This extension has the feature that you can set inside each block in a backend layout which CEs are allowed.