# TYPO3: Backend Layout Condition in TypoScript

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript

I'd like to change the way elements are rendered depending on the page's backend layout.
Changing the fluid styled content template depending on the backend layout works as following:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|backend_layout = 1][globalVar = TSFE:page|backend_layout = 2]
lib.fluidContent.templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:ds_res/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentTemplates/
[global]
```

If it's 1 or 2, then use the other templates.

*However*, this only works if the BE layout is set directly at the page and **not** when it's inherited from its parent.
How to fix this?

Running TYPO3 7.6.15

Comment: Have a look at this Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614470/typoscript-condition-backend-layout-with-slide

Comment: @bschauer I've also seen that post, but how do I use the `lib.backendLayout` inside a condition? `[lib.xx = 1]` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 6):

In TYPO3 7.5 "Backend Layout"-Conditions has been simplified with "pagelayout" in Typoscript. Example:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
  file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = pagelayout
    default = TEXT
    default.value = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Home.html
    3 = TEXT
    3.value = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/1-col.html
    4 = TEXT
    4.value = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/2-col.html
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
field = backend_layout
field.data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
field.ifEmpty = default
```

Maybe this also works in your conditions like this:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page|pagelayout = 1]
```

However, you should **not change the used template file with [xy]-conditions** and prefer using a CASE shown in the example above. Each number is the UID of a `backend_layout` by the way.

Comment: +1 for the pagelayout and simplification. Unfortunately, `[globalVar = TSFE:page|pagelayout = 1]` doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature available which avoids having that code duplicated

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    templateName = TEXT
    templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
    templateName.stdWrap.cObject {
        key.data = pagelayout
        ....
```

Answer (score 2):

In TYPO3 9.5+ you can use typoscript conditions like:

```
[page["backend_layout"] == 'pagets__2']
    page.bodyTagCObject.value.wrap = <body id="uid|" class="fullpage">
[end]
```

Edit:

As [Bernd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6796354/bernd-wilke-%CF%80%CF%86) has mentioned use `backend_layout` only if you need the real defined field. If you need the computed value (e.g. for a sub page getting its layout from the `backend_layout_next_level` from a parent page) use `pagelayout` with a case like:

```
bodyTagCObject = TEXT
bodyTagCObject.value.field = uid
bodyTagCObject.value.wrap.cObject = CASE
bodyTagCObject.value.wrap.cObject{
    
    key.data = pagelayout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = <body id="uid|" class="standard">
    
    pagets__2 = TEXT
    pagets__2.value = <body id="uid|" class="fullpage">
    
}
```

Comment: be careful with this condition: the layout of the current page also can be determined by the field `backend_layout_next_level` of parent pages. since TYPO3 7 there is the pseudo-field `pagelayout` which contains the computed value of these fields.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to implement this solution, don't know much about typoscript. In this condition... what is it exactly the "pagets__2" ?

Comment: @arderoma please start a new question next time for that. Have a look at: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/BackendLayout/Index.html#backend-layout-simple-example where you will find an example for the Backend Layouts config. The "2" in your question is the "exampleKey" in that snippet. So long words short: It's the id of the backend layout.

Answer (score 1):

As you can not handle the inherited layouts in conditions you need to use typoscript. My solution is this:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    templateRootPaths.1 = {$resDir}/Private/Templates
    partialRootPaths.1 = {$resDir}/Private/Partials
    layoutRootPaths.1 = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts

    templateName = TEXT
    templateName.cObject = CASE
    templateName.cObject {
        key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        key.override.field = backend_layout

        #Default Template
        default = TEXT
        default.value = subpage

        # homepage 
        pagets__homepage = TEXT
        pagets__homepage.value = homepage

        pagets__subpage = TEXT
        pagets__subpage.value = subpage
    }
    variables {
        :

        pageLayout = TEXT
        pageLayout.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        pageLayout.override.field = backend_layout

        // since TYPO3 7 this already is computed by the core and this gives the same:
        pageLayout = TEXT
        pageLayout.data = pagelayout

        :
    }
}
```

Avoid using `file` for better implementation with ..RootPaths.

As we use backendlayouts defined in files (which gets included in the pageTSconfig) the key names starting with `pagets__`, you also might use the numbers of backend_layout records.

I use the constant `{$resDir}` to define the root of resources which can be changed in an easy way. In a siteextension this could be:

```
resDir = EXT:site_project1/Resources
```

I also define a fluid variable with the currently active page layout for further differentiation in the templates.

If you want the `...RootPaths` to be different for each layout you need to build cObject with a CASE obejct similar to my selection of the template name.

**In general**: all this could be handled in the fluid templates if you have the backend layout available in your variables: you only need to have one starting template, which calls a layout where all further calls to partials are individualized by the current layout like

```
<f:render partial="{pageLayout}/header" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

We use this solution

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {

templateName = TEXT
templateName.stdWrap {
    cObject = TEXT
    cObject {
        data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
        override.field = backend_layout
        split {
            token = pagets__
            1.current = 1
            1.wrap = |
        }
    }
    ifEmpty = Index
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Layouts
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Partials
        }
        templateRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Templates
        }
}
```

This approach is when u do not have the Backendlayouts in the DB (made through the backend) but include them from files. As there is no uid then you go by the templatename.

Example: 
If you use this PageTS:

```
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
    Blankpage {
        title = Blankpage
        name = Blankpage
        icon = EXT:yourext/Resources/Public/Icons/BackendLayouts/Blankpage.jpg
    config {
        backend_layout {
            colCount = 1
            rowCount = 2
            rows {
                1 {
                    columns {
                        1 {
                            name = Nameofthecolumn
                            colPos = 0
                            colspan = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
                2 {
                    columns {
                        1 {
                            name = Nameofthesecondcolumn
                            colPos = 1
                            colspan = 1
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need a Template.html with the name Blankpage.html within your EXT-Templates.

So you can add more Templates and Backendlayouts without touching the TS again. Simply add PageTS and a html-template.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 11.x:

```
[tree.pagelayout == 2]
   ...
[global]
```

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Feature-88276-TypoScriptConditionForPageLayout.html