# How to automatically edit page configuration and add a template from extension controller?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I am writing an Extbase Extension that automatically creates pages.
So far I have managed to add the pages, and they show up in the page tree. I have also got their page ids saved in variables.

```
 $data = array(
        'pages' => array(
            'NEW_1' => array(
                'pid' => '-1',
                'title' => 'Page1',

            ),
            'NEW_2' => array(
                'pid' => 'NEW_1',
                'title' => 'Page2',
            ),
            'NEW_3' => array(
                'pid' => 'NEW_1',
                'title' => 'Page3',
            ),
            'NEW_4' => array(
                'pid' => 'NEW_1',
                'title' => 'Page4',
            ),
        )
    );
    $tce = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\DataHandling\\DataHandler');
    $tce->stripslashes_values = 0;
    $dataHandler->reverseOrder = 0;
    $tce->start($data, []);
    $tce->process_datamap();
    \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::setUpdateSignal('updatePageTree');
    $tce->clear_cacheCmd('pages');

            $Page1id=$tce->substNEWwithIDs['NEW_1'];
    $Page2id=$tce->substNEWwithIDs['NEW_2'];
    $Page3id=$tce->substNEWwithIDs['NEW_3'];
    $Page4id=$tce->substNEWwithIDs['NEW_4'];
```

Now I want to automatically add a Fluid-Template to these pages but I can't figure out how to do that without manually adding one in the backend. Does someone know how to do that?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you mean Fluid-Template, where in backend do you manually add them in backend? Or do you mean TypoScript-Template, where you would configure Fluid-Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fluid templates are not assigned to pages immediately you need to set a layout which selects a template. You have multiple fields in a `pages` record. The most common fields probably are `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level`. You also could use the field `pagelayout` but I prefer `backend_layout` as it has a nice inheritance mode, where you could except single pages.
Solutions could be found in the web or [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630348/typo3-backend-layout-condition-in-typoscript).

If your fluid template is selected with one of these fields you could set this field like any other field while creating the new records.

```
$data = array(
    'pages' => array(
        'NEW_1' => array(
            'pid' => '-1',
            'title' => 'Page1',
            'backend_layout' => 'SpecialPageLayout', 
        ),
        'NEW_2' => array(
            'pid' => 'NEW_1',
            'title' => 'Page2',
            'backend_layout' => 'SpecialPageLayout', 
        ),
     :
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)  I will try it out this evening.